# PhoneGap/iOS disconnect on lost focus?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

When my PhoneGap application gets push to the background and is there for sometime it disconnects from the server. If possible I would like to keep this connection open. If this is not possible I would at least like to be able to react to an event when focus in resumed so I can bring everything up to date.

Please let me know how best I can handle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot easily have a background thread running in javascript - when the application is pushed to the background, it ceases to execute.

You can however bind to the [resume](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume) event to restore everything you need when your app is brought to front:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
   // restore context
}
```

Comment: ok, awesome, thanks -- btw does an event fire when it is pushed to the bg also? That would be useful too

Comment: Check out the `pause` event, be sure to notice the iOS quirks there aswell.